# Laravel: Variable in trans

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to add variables to the trans (for example i'm in a foreach)

What I have:

`{{ _('enum\partnerType.$partner->typeName')}}`

The $partner->typeName returns with `private` or `corporation` and I have transvalue for both key, but I got back this on blade:

> enum\partnerType.$partner->typeName

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are passing the variable in incorrectly, you have the `'` in the wrong position change it to look like the following:

```
{{ _('enum/partnerType.' . $partner->typeName) }}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but with `{{ _('enum/partnerType.' . $partner->typeName)}}`  :)

Comment: Also, if this is correct you should accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check your quotes. Do you probably mean:

```
{{ _('enum\partnerType'.$partner->typeName)}}
```